# Eclipse apply only one format rule

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to format my code so that all the open curly braces are not on new lines.

This is possible in eclipse but then all other format settings get executed as well, I want only one format rule to be applied. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Java Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit [Active Profile] -> You can do what and all you formatting you need and what and all you don't need

[image: Below is the screenshot where you can make remove the format you need and don't need]

Or May be You can create a new profile for that alone and you can use it rather than changing the default ones.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to apply **only one** format rule and turn off all other format rules.